# Get MD5 value for array in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have a table of array, for example

```
test=# select * from path;
          path      
---------------
{4,3,2,1}
{4,1,2,3}
{1,2,3,4}
{1,4,3,2}
```

actually, the tuples are repeated, and I want to remove redundent rows. 
one issue is how to say they are same. my method is using fingerprint method. for example

```
v=md5(1)+md5(2)+md5(3)+md5(4)
```

for different rows, the v are same.

I wonder whether use postgresql could calculate v value? because it the path can be any length array, how can I write a query to get the v value ? thanks.

Comment: Why are you messing around with fingerprint formulas when SQL has the feature you are asking for built-in: `select distinct * from path`.

Comment: distinct could not deal with array ... @DourHighArch